# HTML5 audio tag sound can't be heard on PC

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I try to play a sound with the HTML5 audio tag in a web page and I have some issues to heard it.

On Mac, I can hear it flawlessly. In PC, there is a click sound at the beginning, another at the end, and nothing else. But when I click on the sound icon on the OS, the "waves" are showing.

I do not know if it's related but I have a div which is toggled when the audio end. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="block">Listen.</div>
<div class="bande_audio">
    <span>1</span>
    <audio id="audio1" preload="auto" controls>
        <source src="audio/heartbeat-slow_M1Vtl3VO.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source src="audio/heartbeat-slow_M1Vtl3VO.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        Your browser does not support audio element.
    </audio>                
    <div class="enonce">
        Which activity can you associate to this heartbeat?
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(".question" + index +" audio").bind("ended", function(){
    $(".block").toggle();
});
```

Can you help me? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I tested the codecs and it's not the issue here. Also, the tests were made on Chrome 52.0.2743.116, on OSX El Capitan and Windows 7.

Comment: did you check if your browser supports ogg or mp3? Just because it supports `<audio>` doesn't mean it supports THOSE codecs. the html5 spec is silent on what codecs must be supported, so it's entirely up to the browser makers to decide what they want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll definitely check this out. But I tried on the same browser (same version) in the two plateform. Is it possible that from Mac to PC, Chrome has not the same codecs?

Comment: This might also be caused by some kind of very specific encoding problem in the MP3 file, such that the player used by OSX can play it but the one used by Windows cannot because of a bug (either on the part of the encoder or the player). Can you try with a different file?

Comment: Thanks @apsillers, I'll investigate this. It could be this, when I think about it. I believe the sounds were modified on GarageBand. I'll check and come back. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, there was a problem with the encoding. The file were modified with GarageBand and Windows could not read it. Editing the original with Audacity solved the issue.

Thanks a lot, Marc B. and aspillers for your enlightenments. They were really useful.